# How to findall element with attribute with namespace which is not listed in the xml header

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

my xml looks like this
[image: source xml]

I want to target all tags `<langSet xml:lang="en">`. As you see, "xml" is not listed in "xmlns" attributes in the root. I'm using `xml.etree.ElementTree` to `parse` and `getroot` to initialize value of `root` below.

So this call works just fine, but returns all languages:

```
root.findall('.//langSet')
```

And this call is what i need, but it returns empty list:

```
root.findall('.//langSet[@{xml}:lang="en"]')
```

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `xml` namespace prefix is predefined (it does not need to be declared in the XML document). But the ElementTree library still requires an explicit mapping:

```
nsmap = {"xml": "http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace"}
```

`nsmap` can then be used in the `findall()` call:

```
root.findall('.//langSet[@xml:lang="en"]', namespaces=nsmap)
```

You could also use this syntax:

```
root.findall('.//langSet[@{http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace}lang="en"]')
```

Answer (score 0):

The "xml" namespace prefix is predefined, both in XML documents and in XPath. So you can simply do

```
.//langSet[@xml:lang='en']
```

Also, XPath has a lang() function allowing

```
.//langSet[lang('en')]
```

This doesn't do quite the same thing: (a) it also considers the `@xml:lang` attribute on ancestor elements, and (b) it will match not only `xml:lang="en"`, but also a more specific language code such as `xml:lang="en-GB"`.

Incidentally, "uk" is the language code for Ukranian: I don't know if that's what you had in mind.

Comment: Thank you for answers, but first gives "SyntaxError: prefix 'xml' not found in prefix map", and second gives "SyntaxError: invalid predicate". The first one is correct but not complete. as i read in the next asnwer --- the namespaces arg is needed. P.S.: and yes, "uk" is for Ukrainian. Basically i need a map of terms from the file (EN => UK), i it may contain other languages, and the order of them is not defined, so i select EN and then look for UK. thank you again for you time :)

Comment: OK, re-reading the XPath 1.0 spec I see that there's nothing that says the XML namespace is always present in the context; the default context is processor-dependent. So you probably need to declare it explicitly, as you would with any other namespace. The namespace URI is `http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace`.